# Safari and Edge can't load sites (sometimes, very often!)

Tags: mobile-safari, microsoft-edge, fiddler, iis-8, plesk-onyx

Please, I need help about a strange behaviour of our server.
The server (Microsoft Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5, Plesk Onyx 17.8.11) hosts a lot of sites developed in different technologies (PHP, ASP.NET, HTML+JS).
These sites work well with Chrome and FireFox both on Windows and MacOS, but Safari on iOS 11 & 12 is unable to open the sites, so I get this error "safari can't open the page because the server where this page is located isn't responding".
**Sometimes** Safari open the site for a few minutes, then it don't work again.
I experience a similar in Microsoft Edge: it can't open the sites unless I run Fiddler, in this case it works well.
I'm getting crazy, because this behaviour seems to be unpredictable.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many compatibility issues for safari (I can't speak for edge). If you inspect the CSS code of these particular sites that you are having trouble running, and with some research, you will likely be able to identify the lines of code that are causing the sites not to load on Safari.

Comment: Can you provide a specific information about the issue. do you got any error? You can try to provide us the site address. We will try to make a test with Edge and try to produce the issue.Then we can try to provide a  suggestion that can solve your issue.

Comment: Here's some site involved by this issue:
https://www.agronomict.it
https://www.ording.ct.it
https://dpautomazioni.com